# Distinct Lists inside of RDD in Spark, not the whole RDD

Tags: python, mapreduce, apache-spark, pyspark

I have such RDD: `[(1,1,2),(2,2,3)]`

I want to have: `[1,2,2,3]`

Hint: middle step: `(1,2),(2,3)`

My code:

```
suchRDD.flatMap(lambda k:k).distinct()
```

.. will produce:

```
[1,2,3]
```

which is not what I want. (never mind the different types of braces please)

How to reduce on each nested list and then flatten out to get the wanted result? (Please no list comprehension examples, reminder: this is Spark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this step `suchRDD.flatMap(lambda k:k)` you will get:
[1,2,2,3]
It's impossible to know which number came from which set, so you should distinct the tuple before flatMap. To to so, you can use set(), the build-in function in Python to get distinct items.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(1,1,2),(2,2,3)])
rdd.map(set).flatMap(lambda x:x).collect()
```

Comment: You are my personal hero.